# Notification system for SP 2010 portal users

Tags: 2010, alert

There is a task to implement the notification system in SP2010 portal (~ 12 thousand users).

Need to solve following tasks with notification:

1. List of items where each item has a group of users and date on when an e-mail should be sent to these group of users with some item data.
2. Notification about changes in user-selected web sites (immediately, daily, weekly). Similar to the standard subscription management, but only the structure of the web can be nested and non-trivial.
3. Alerts in the Discussions list on the chosen topic and automatic subscription on a user-created topic.
4. In custom commenting solution for list items. All comments are stored in a hidden list. Needed to inform the user about responses to his comments. 4.

I intend to solve these problems in the following way:

1st task - Workflow (EventReceiver is not suitable, because of the timer needed to send a message)
2nd task – generate programmatically SPAlerts for some lists in the selected web site.
The 3rd is a standard Alert-s in the list and programmatic creating of SPAlert for newly added topic in EventReceiver.
4th is a TimerJob with analysis of changes in comments list and sending e-mail notifications when needed.

*Actually want to hear the advice of knowledgeable people working with the system of alerts in SP 2010. How is it better to implement and whether any restrictions in my implementation.*